# Bitwise operation in large list as fast as possible in c#

Tags: c#, performance

I have a list from 10,000 long value
and I want to compare that data withe 100,000 other long value
compare is a bitwise operation -->

```
if (a&b==a) count++;
```

which algoritm I can use for getting best performance?

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of Int64s in which B has all the bits turned on as A?

Comment: Do you want to check if the 100,000 items are in the initial list?

Comment: If you sort both lists first you can then count the number of matches in just one parallel pass over both of them.

Comment: BitArray would require conversion of the Int64/UInt64 values to a byte array since it doesn't handle those data types natively, so I think you're already doing the right thing with a simple bitwise comparison.

Theoretically, an *inequality* comparison can resolve faster than equality, but I seriously doubt it would make a difference on any modern processor.

Comment: @agent-j yes I'm trying to count that

Comment: You could try using a `for` loop over a plain old array. That's not asymptotically faster of course, but using Lists (and especially LINQ) has more overhead associated with it.

Comment: Just to be pedantic (sorry): `a & b == a` will not compile if `a` and `b` are of type `long` because it means `a & (b == a)` and there is no "and" (`&`) operator overload taking a `long` and a `bool`. Missing parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check `a` against each `b` whether some predicate is true. So a naive solution to your problem would be as follows:

```
var result = aList.Sum(a => bList.Count(b => (a & b) == a));
```

I'm not sure this can really be sped up for an arbitrary predicate, because you can't get around checking each `a` against each `b`. What you could try is run the query in parallel:

```
var result = aList.AsParallel().Sum(a => bList.Count(b => (a & b) == a));
```

*Example:*

`aList`: 10,000 random `long` values; `bList`: 100,000 random `long` values.

- without `AsParallel`: 00:00:13.3945187
- with `AsParallel`: 00:00:03.8190386

Comment: Just because you split the work between more people doesn't mean you are working more efficiently.

Comment: thanx why when I use parallel performance reduce and proccess took more time?

Comment: @32bitkid: Why should I work more efficiently if I have enough people? ;-) I think your other comment is spot on: try this naive solution with AsParallel first, and if it doesn't meet the requirements, think about tries etc.

Comment: My cpu is dual core 64bit but perfromance in parallel mode reduce. why?

Comment: parrall speed problem was because of my fault,I'll mark your response as answer just aList.Foreach is faster when I tested, thanx alot

Answer (score 2):

Put all of your `a`s into a trie data structure, where the first level of the tree corresponds to the first bit of the number, the second to the second bit, and so on. Then, for each `b`, walk down the trie; if this bit is 1 in `b`, then count both branches, or if this bit is 0 in `b`, count only the 0 branch of the trie. I think this should be O(n+m), but I haven't thought about it very hard.

You can probably get the same semantics but with better cache characteristics by sorting the list of `a`s and using the sorted list in much the same way as the trie. This is going to be slightly worse in terms of number of operations - because you'll have to search for stuff a lot of the time - but the respect for the CPU cache might more than make up for it.

N.B. I haven't thought about correctness much harder than I've thought about big-O notation, which is to say probably not enough.

Comment: I would try this, directly after i profiled the simple solution and determined it was, in-fact, an unacceptable bottleneck.